# Overlapping hboxes

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, text-decorations

How can I change the following macro to get a rule in hbox 2 that is just as wide as the text in hbox 1 and remove parameter #2?

```
\def\m#1#2{
   \leavevmode
   \hbox to#2{
      \hbox to#2{\hfil\lower9pt\hbox{\it#1}\hfil}% hbox 1
      \hss
      \hbox to#2{\leaders\hrule\hfil}}}% hbox 2
```

P.S. Solutions just with TeX and plain TeX are preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for manual measuring. `\hrule` automatically extends to the width of the surrounding vertical box (if the parameter `width` is not given):

```
\def\m#1{%
  \leavevmode
  \vtop{%
    \hrule
    \kern2pt % vertical space between rule and text
    \hbox{\it#1\/}%
  }%
}
abc\m{foo bar}def\m{man}ghi
\bye
```

> [image: Result]

Or if the distance between rule and text base line should be constant.

```
\def\m#1{%
  \leavevmode
  \vtop{%
    \hrule
    \vbox to .7\baselineskip{%
      \vfill
      \hbox{\it#1\/}%
    }%
  }%
}
abc\m{foo}def\m{man}ghi\m{gpq}jkm
\bye
```

> [image: Result]

**Remark:**

- Both examples add an italics correction at the end of the text.

Comment: Why does this solution need the `\leavevmode` command?

Comment: @AngelTsankov: `\leavevmode` is inherited from the question. You can also use it without. Then it does not start a paragraph in vertical mode.